# Order and sequence hierchical data using C# - Sequence Manipulation Linked List scenario

Tags: c#, algorithm, sequence

How do I do ordering and add sequence number to following data using C# ?

```
Id    NextStepId
AS4   AS5
AS1   AS2
AS5   NULL
AS3   AS4
AS2   AS3
```

I want the output as following order -

```
Id    NextStepId SEQ
AS1   AS2         1
AS2   AS3         2
AS3   AS4         3
AS4   AS5         4
AS5   NULL        5
```

More Info -

```
Public class WFStep{
public string Step{get;set;}
public string NextStep{get;set;}
}

List<WFStep> s = new List<WFStep>();
```

Comment: ...any code? Initial attempts?

Comment: What is your `data structure`?

Comment: Is this structure in a datatable, collection, array, etc..?

Comment: Clarification - the data structure is a collection List<Step> where Step is a class with Id (string) and NextStep (string)

Answer (score 1):

In general what you're building is a linked list, where each node points to its successor.

If we assume that your input is valid, that is:

1. It contains one node that has no successor.
2. It contains one node that has nothing pointing to it (i.e. the head node).
3. Each node is pointed to by only one other node (except the node described in #2, which has nothing pointing to it).

Create a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Using your data definitions:

```
foreach (var step in s)
{
    dict.Add(step.Step, step.NextStep);
}
```

Now, there is one key in the dictionary that is not in any node's value. (i.e. One `Step` that isn't also a `NextStep`.) For example, `AS1` does not exist in the values. You can get that one key by:

```
var firstNode = dict.Keys.Except(dict.Values).First();
```

`Except` will give you all of the items in `Keys` that aren't in `Values`. If your data meets the criteria outlined above, there will be one and only one such key.

That's the head of the list. You can start there to walk the list in order.

```
int seq = 1;
var key = firstNode;
while (key != null)
{
    var next = dict[key];
    Console.WriteLine("Id: {0}, NextStepId: {1}, SEQ: {2}",
        key, next, seq);
    ++seq;
    key = next;
}
```

Likely there's a more succinct way to do this using LINQ.

The beauty of this solution is that it doesn't assume anything about the lexicographical order of the ids. The order could be:

```
Foo     Bar
Bar     Fooby
Fooby   Zoom
Zoom    Zip
Zip     Alpha
Alpha   Queen
Queen   NULL
```

and it would still work as long as the three conditions above are met.